# Jetpack Compose BackPressHandler fails to intercept back presses after onResume

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, onbackpressed, android-jetpack-navigation

In my Jetpack Compose project I'm using **BackPressHandler** from Android examples. Everything works as expected until I **pause and resume** the app. At this point **BackPressHandler** is not intercepting back button anymore and navigation just defaults to regular back press behaviour.

Was able to recreate the issue in a demo project, please see code example:

https://gist.github.com/vitalnik/2a444c20cb9f370c405ee1ddb86d3e66

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use `BackPressHandler` anymore, since that article was written, system `BackHandler` was added, so you can switch. It doesn't have such an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply, Philip! Works just fine now.

Comment: I wonder why I can not resolve BackHandler in android studio, even custom adding to import doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Hi like @Philip explained use `BackHandler`, it highjacks your backpress when it's enabled.
one example I use this is with combination of bottom sheet state `isExpanded` so when its true backpress could dismiss the bottomSheet and also get disabled itself, try to use this kind of combination.

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
BackHandler(enabled = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isExpanded){
  scope.launch{
     bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use **BackHandler** instead of BackPressHandler, but this will not solve the problem directly. You can check the issue and what caused the issue from the link below.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279118447

**SOLUTION 1**

This issue has been fixed in navigation (androidx.navigation:navigation-compose) version 2.7.0-beta01. If your version is lower than 2.7.0-beta01, you have to update your version to 2.7.0-beta01 or higher.

**SOLUTION 2**

You can fix the issue by using the composable below.

```
@Composable
fun BackHandlerWithLifecycle(
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    var refreshBackHandler by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    OnLifecycleEvent { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> refreshBackHandler = false
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> refreshBackHandler = true
            else -> Unit
        }
    }
    if (refreshBackHandler) {
        BackHandler(enabled = enabled) {
            onBack()
        }
    }
}
```